# root integrity check: System check FAIL!

Tags: recovery-mode, htc-desire

In my attempts to troubleshoot a [Notifications volume turning itself down](https://forums.androidcentral.com/samsung-galaxy-s3/390156-notifications-volume-turning-itself-down.html) problem on my HTC Desire 728, I selected in "system recovery" menu the option of `root integrity check`.

It ran quickly, displaying the following:

> Now check begins, please wait.....
>
> load source zip file fail
>
> System check FAIL!!

In the context of HTC, what does "root integrity check" actually means? Is it just an `fsck`? If so why does it need to "load source zip file"? What does this `FAIL!!` mean?

Comment: Wouldn't it be better to describe the "mysterious problem" to us, instead of following a possibly unrelated path?

Comment: @DeathMaskSalesman You're right. See edit in the OP.

Answer (score -1):

Root integrity check fail means some person have modified apk or file on your android it means they could also spy on you because every apk have java permissions that you might not know off unless u check on computer with adb commands and remove the modified apk and files manually